# Loading content after adding an element to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery's load() to change the content of a div.
To call this method I add a click handler to a HTML element, e.g. an img, which will call this method. On mousedown, I add another img to the DOM right after the clicked img which overlays it exactly. I do this to show the user that a click has happened. On mouseup I hide it.
I show it again when the user clicks again on that img so I don't remove it from the DOM.

This works basically but it gets me into trouble when calling the load method on click. The click event is not executed unless I hold the mouse button pressed for around one second.
When I do not insert that overlay image after the pressed image (but e.g. before it in the DOM) the onClick works fine.

Binding the load() to the mouseUp event comes with the same behaviour as the onClick.

Can anybody give me a hint how to solve this problem? A workaround is to bind the load() to the mousedown event. But this is not what I want.

```
element.on('click', function() {
    $('#content').load(target, function(event) {
        [...]
     });
});

element.on('vmousedown', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 1 || event.which == 0) {
        showOnClickImage($(this));
    }
});

element.on('vmouseup mouseleave', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 1 || event.which == 0) { // left mousebutton or touch respectively
        hideOnClickImage($(this));    
    }
});

function showOnClickImage(element) {
    if (element.data("onClickImageOverlay")) {
        element.data("onClickImageOverlay").show();
    } else if (element.data("onclickimage")) {
        [read attributes]
        var overlayImage = $("<img data-onClickImageOverlay src='" + src + "' style='position:absolute; width:" + width + "; height:" + height + "; left:" + left + "; top:" + top + ";' />");
        element.after(overlayImage); // removing this line makes load() work
        element.data("onClickImageOverlay", overlayImage);
    }
    clearTimeout(clickTimeout);
    clickTimeout = setTimeout(function() {hideOnClickImage(element);}, 300);
}


function hideOnClickImage(element) {
    if (element.data("onClickImageOverlay")) {
        element.data("onClickImageOverlay").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask, why you don't want to bind the load-thing to `mousedown`?

Comment: Firstly because the behaviour is different then. One expects the button event to run after letting go of the mouse button and not right after pressing it. Some people might keep the button pressed for any reason such as to call the context menu on mobile devices. Secondly I would like to understand what the problem is. I guess there is something important in connection with event firing and DOM I just haven't understood yet. Just ignoring problems usually results in further problems later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
When showing another image on mouse down, this overlay image then catches the mouseup event because it is at mouseup time on top of the original image. That is as well why the onclick doesn't work on the original image.
Further, when showing the overlay image on mousedown, the mouseleave event is fired. This makes sense because the mouse pointer leaves the original image.

The mouseup of course worked when waiting longer on the element than setTimeout() lasted. setTimeout() hid the overlay image after 0.3 seconds.

I finally decided to bind the mouseup listener to both images.